# Как создать изображение под другим tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хочу сделать чтобы при выполнении условия появлялось изображение, но оно появляется так, что перекрывает другие и их не видно, как создать изображение чтобы оно появлялось под этими и не перекрывало их?
Вот код типа игры

```py
import sys
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, ALL, NW
from keyboard import *
from time import *
import threading

class Cons:
    roadSpeed = 20
class Game(Canvas):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            width=1024, height=900, highlightthickness=0, background="black"
        )
        self.start()
        self.pack()
    def start(self):
        self.inGame = True
        self.score = 0
        self.barrierX = 128
        self.barrierY = -500

        self.loadImages()

        self.createObjects()
        self.locateBarrier()
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.keyPressed)
        self.after(100, self.onTimer)

    def loadImages(self):
        self.icar = Image.open("ttt.png")
        self.car = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.icar)
        self.ienemy = Image.open("enemy.png")
        self.barrier = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.ienemy)
        self.iroad = Image.open("1396441575.png")
        self.road = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.iroad)

    def createObjects(self):
        self.create_image(512, 502, image=self.road, tag="road")
        self.create_image(128, 650, image=self.car, tag="car")
        self.create_text(
            30, 10, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score),
            tag="score", fill="white"
        )

    def moveLeft(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 - 256 > 2:
            self.move(car[0], -256, 0)

    def moveRight(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 + 256 < 1022:
            self.move(car[0], 256, 0)

    def checkBarrierCollision(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        overlap = self.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        for i in overlap:
            for j in range(0, len(barrier)):
                if barrier[j] == i:
                    self.inGame = False

    def moveRoadAndBarrier(self):
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y < 502:
                cnt += 1
        if cnt == 0:
            self.create_image(512, -502, image=self.road, tag="road")
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        z = 0
        while z < len(road):
            self.move(road[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1
        z = 0
        while z < len(barrier):
            self.move(barrier[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1

    def locateBarrier(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        for i in range(0, len(barrier)):
            self.delete(barrier[i])
        r = random.randint(1, 3)
        for i in range(r):
            r1 = random.randint(1, 4)
            r2 = r1 - 1
            self.create_image(256 * r2 + 128, 20, image=self.barrier, tag="barrier")

    def keyPressed(self, e):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x, y = self.coords(car)
        key = e.keysym
        leftKey = "Left"
        if key == leftKey and x >= 128:
            self.moveLeft()
        rightKey = "Right"
        if key == rightKey and x <= 896:
            self.moveRight()

    def onTimer(self):
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y == 1502:
                self.delete(road[i])
        self.drawScore()
        self.checkBarrierCollision()
        if self.inGame:
            self.moveRoadAndBarrier()
            self.after(100, self.onTimer)
        else:
            self.gameOver()

    def drawScore(self):
        score = self.find_withtag("score")
        self.itemconfigure(score, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score))
    def gameOver(self):
        self.delete(ALL)
        self.create_text(self.winfo_width() / 2, self.winfo_height() / 2,
                         text="Игра окончена", fill="blue")
class Car(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.master.title('ооаоаа')
        self.board = Game()
        self.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    ooaoaa = Car()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Мне нужно чтобы в moveRoadAndBarrier создавалось изображение дороги, которое далее не будет перекрывать машины.
Вот изображения, использованные в коде.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам обязательно, чтобы изображение дороги появлялось при выполнении условия? Может установить его, как background?
bg = PhotoImage(file = "Your_image.png'')

Comment: @SenaS, если делать фоном, то нельзя будет сделать движущуюся дорогу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно после добавления картинки дороги понижать ее по уровню ("слоям") ниже картинок машин:

```
if cnt == 0:
    self.create_image(512, -502, image=self.road, tag="road")
    self.tag_lower("road")
```

Метод `tag_lower` перемещает объект (или несколько объектов с общим тегом) на самый низ "стопки" объектов на холсте. См. описание методов холста здесь: [Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Еще небольшое дополнение: вы создаете объект-холст `Game` в методе класса-фрейме `Car`, но фактически холст крепится к окну, а не к фрейму `Car` из-за того что в `Game` не передается родительский объект. Чтобы крепилось к фрейму, можно поправить так:

```
class Game(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(
            parent, width=1024, height=900, highlightthickness=0, background="black"
        )

...

class Car(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
```

Еще, немного не правильно, что `Car` меняет заголовок окна, в котором этот фрейм размещен. Если вы вдруг решите поместить этот фрейм в другой фрейм, изменение заголовка перестанет работать. Лучше заголовок менять в функции `main()`.

Также размещение созданных объектов (через `.pack()`, например) лучше не делать внутри этих объектов, а делать это снаружи: допустим, у вас в окне размещено несколько объектов, и чтобы поменять `pack` на `grid` или поменять параметры размещения вам придется заходить в каждый объект. Если размещение "вытащить" из объектов, то оно будет для всех объектов данного фрейма/окна в пределах одной функции, и будет легко его поменять.